# Difference between Supervisor and DynamicSupervisor

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor

Someone can explain difference between Supervisor and DynamicSupervisor in Elixir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A DynamicSupervisor is a supervisor designed to supervise and manage
>   many children dynamically.

This is the main purpose of a DynamicSupervisor-- you can read the full [proposal on Github](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/issues/10)

At a high level here are the four main goals outlined in the proposal:

- Simplify the API and usage of both Supervisor modules. Most
  of the documentation in the Supervisor module is full of
  conditionals: "if the supervisor type is :simple_one_for_one,
  it will behave as X, otheriwse as Y." The differences in
  behaviour with little surrounding context makes supervisors
  hard to learn, understand and use;
- Provide out-of-the-box supervisor sharding for cases where
  the supervisor itself may be a scalability concern;
- Provide a built-in registry to avoid developers unecessarily
  using dependencies like gproc or incorrect dependencies like
  global;
- Implement the GenStage specification
  so dynamic supervisors can subscribe to producers and spawn
  children dynamically based on demand;

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation very interesting

https://blog.carbonfive.com/2018/01/30/comparing-dynamic-supervision-strategies-in-elixir-1-5-and-1-6/